# Как вызвать C++ функцию из python'a?

Tags: python, c++

Допустим, есть у меня файл `hello.cpp` следующего содержания:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello() {
    cout << "Hello!" << endl;
}
```

Как эту функцию можно вызвать из программы на **python**?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Динамическая библиотека C++ в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731789/23044)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В том виде, в котором Вы привели - никак (ну или почти никак). С/C++ код должен быть написан по определенным правилам. В документации питона есть раздел, где все детально описано - [Extending Python with C or C++](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html).

Ваш код (заготовка) скорее всего должен выглядеть где то так:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
hello(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: А как мне потом эту функцию из питона вызвать?

Comment: А Вы смотрели статью по ссылке? там все как раз начинается с питонового кода. Прочитайте ее внимательно. Пойдите на habrahabr.ru, в строке поиска введите python c++ и получите кучу примеров и статей на эту тему.

Comment: Си функцию можно вызвать, не создавая расширения для Питона. К примеру, используя [ctypes, cffi модули](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/731959/23044), ещё [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460018/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Модуль ctypes позволяет вам взаимодействовать с кодом на С и c++ из Python
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

К ответу [@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim) еще можно добавить предложение попробовать [Boost::Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/index.html). Весьма удобная вещь для создания  бинарных модулей для Питона на С++.