# Ошибка конвертации параметра: вызов С++ функции, принимающей массив из Питона с помощью ctypes

Tags: c++, python, dll, ctypes

Подключил .dll, написанную в c++ в python. Решил попробовать вызвать функцию, но ругается на ошибку "Don't know how to convert parameter 1". Как ее можно исправить?

Код функции на С++.

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) int* SortFunc(int mass[], int n) {
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)     
        for(int j = i; j > 0 && mass[j-1] > mass[j]; j--) 
        {
            int temp = mass[j - 1];
            mass[j - 1] = mass[j];
            mass[j] = temp;
        }
    return mass;
}
```

Код программы на Python:

```
from ctypes import*
mydll = CDLL("D:\MyMathFuncs\MathFuncsDll.dll")
a = []
for i in range(n):
    a.append(int(input()))
print(a)
b = mydll.SortFunc(a, n)
print(b)
```

Comment: в сторону: для Виндовых путей следует использовать `r""`  raw строковые константы, например, `'\n'` -- это один символ новой строки, а `r'\n'` это два символа обратный слэш и `n`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes` не умеет автоматически преобразовывать Питон список в int массив (точнее, указатель на массив).

Можно создать ctypes массив из списка:

```
import ctypes

python_list = [1, 2, 3]
a = (ctypes.c_int * len(python_list))(*python_list)
print(a[:])
SortFunc(a, len(a))
print(a[:])
```

Я бы рассмотрел использование `numpy` массивов для подобных вещей, чтобы избежать ненужного копирования:

```
import ctypes
import numpy # $ sudo apt-get install python-numpy

a = numpy.arange(10, dtype=ctypes.c_int)
print(a)
SortFunc(a.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)), a.size)
print(a)
```

Чтобы передать `a` numpy массив как есть, можно явно [определить типы параметров функции, чтобы включить автоматическое преобразования для `numpy` аргументов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868051/4279):

```
import ctypes
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

SortFunc.argtypes = [ndpointer(ctypes.c_int, flags=("C_CONTIGUOUS", "WRITEABLE")),
                     ctypes.c_int]

SortFunc(a, a.size)
```

Comment: А что с подключением dll? Нам задали лабораторную работу, где нужно подключить ее в python, но сам язык мы не изучали. Не могли бы вы еще объяснить, почему убрали эту строчку? mydll = CDLL("D:\MyMathFuncs\MathFuncsDll.dll")

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратов: я её не привёл потому что она должна работать как есть (как в коде в вопросе, представьте `SortFunc = mydll.SortFunc` где-нибудь сверху). Точнее я просто не подумал о разнице между cdecl и stdcall и просто предположил, что правильные соглашения используются.

Comment: После замены `from ctypes import*` на  `import ctypes` он стал писать вот такую вот вещь: name 'CDLL' is not defined

Comment: `ctypes.CDLL`..

Comment: И последний вопрос: `a = (ctypes.c_int * len(python_list))` подобное описание массива не позволяет мне вернуть массив из функции. Т.е. я описал массив `b = (ctypes.c_int * len(python_list))`, вызвал функцию из dll, которая должна вернуть массив типа int, но после `print(b[:])` пишет, что 'int' object is not subscriptable. Для возврата массива нужно какое-то свое описание? Массив b будет такой же длинны, как и a.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКондратов: в данном случае, функция изменяет переданный массив, поэтому возвращаемое значение следует игнорировать (`L.sort()` vs. `copied = sorted(L)`). `c_int * n` -- это *тип*, а не сам массив. Для ясности, можно `ArrayType = c_int*n`, `a = ArrayType(1, 2, 3)`. Если Вы хотите вернуть новый массив (как `sorted()`), то отдельный вопрос задайте (кратко: необходимо объявить тип результата `SortFunc.restype` и возможно преобразовать из указателя (`ctypes.POINTER(ArrayType)` тип) в массив: [`b = ctypes.cast(result, POINTER(ArrayType)).contents`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7543675/4279)