# Как открыть С++ DLL из Python3

Tags: c++, python, ctypes

Написал на с++ dll. Как вызвать ее из python 3 с помощью ctypes?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wrap1.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
        double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Гуглить](http://blablacode.ru/programmirovanie/542) не пробовали? Или [вот](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) ещё

Comment: @MrMorgan: Stack Overflow это место назначения куда гугл посылает. Если думаете, что уже есть такой вопрос на Stack Overflow, голосуйте за закрытие как дубликата. Если такого вопроса, нет и вы думаете, что знаете решение, то опубликуйте как ответ здесь. Наконец, ссылка в виде комментария может быть также полезной, особенно если вы думаете что она содержит решение. [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2013/23044)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Динамическая библиотека C++ в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/731789/23044)

Comment: @jfs я привел ссылки с решениями

Comment: @MrMorgan: вы думаете, что я ссылок не заметил? Заметил, и явно этот случай упомянул.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Ошибка конвертации параметра: вызов С++ функции, принимающей массив из Питона с помощью ctypes](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/459996/23044)

Answer (score 2):

Я пару минут погуглил и пришёл к такому варианту:

1. Добавляете в исходник

   ```
   extern "C" {
       double MathFuncs_Multiply(double a, double b) {
           return MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(a, b);
       }
   }
   ```
2. В python

   ```
   from ctypes import CDLL, c_double

   lib = CDLL("MathFuncs.dll")
   func = lib.MathFuncs_Multiply
   func.restype = c_double

   res = func(c_double(2.0), c_double(3.2))
   ```

Возможно есть и более изящные решения.