# Вызов C++ dll из python: builtins.OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: c++, python, windows, dll, ctypes

Пытаюсь вызвать С++ dll с python. Выдает такую ошибку:

```
File "C:\Python34\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
builtins.OSError: [WinError 126] Не найден указанный модуль
```

Подскажите что делать

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "wrap1.h"
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs
{
        double MyMathFuncs::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}


extern "C" {
    double MathFuncs_Multiply(double a, double b) {
        return MathFuncs::MyMathFuncs::Multiply(a, b);
    }
}
```

И вызов с питона

```
from ctypes import CDLL, c_double

lib = CDLL("wrap1.dll")
func = lib.MathFuncs_Multiply
func.restype = c_double

res = func(c_double(2.0), c_double(3.2))
print(res)
```

Comment: Больше вашего кода

Comment: Добавьте этот код и питоничий код в вопрос через кнопку править. В комментах код неразборчивый. Делал такую же вещь: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/440f2d0841a1bef37906b48117a079d4d1e06c68/using_custom_dll

Comment: Уверен, ошибка в том, что dll не нашлось. dll лежит в той же папке что и .py? А сам .py файл из какой папки запускается

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как открыть С++ DLL из Python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/781741/23044)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как открыть С++ DLL из Python3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/781741/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%a1-dll-%d0%b8%d0%b7-python3)

Answer (score 0):

Вызываемая .dll лежит в каталоге, отличном от того, где .py, и этот каталог не указан в PATH.
Проверте так:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("wrap1.dll")
```

или с указанием пути (слэши прямые!!!):

```
>>> ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("c:/path/wrap1.dll")
```